# Fuelphp orm if id not exsitst

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I ran into a small problem what i cant really solve.

I created a delete function for videos in fuel php with orm, and maybe its a but stupid but i cant really figure out how to redirext the user if and id doest not exsits.

here is my code

```
public function action_delete($id)
    {

        $deletevideo = Model_Video::find($id);

        if($deletevideo->user_id != Session::get('sentry_user')):
            Session::set_flash('fail', 'The video you want to remove is not yours, we logged this activity');
            Response::redirect(Uri::base() . "myvideos");
        else:
            unlink(realpath("users/video/" . $deletevideo->video_preview));
            unlink(realpath("users/video/" . $deletevideo->video_file));
            $deletevideo->delete();
            Response::redirect(Uri::base() . "myvideos");
        endif;
    }
```

html

```
<a href="<?php echo Uri::base(); ?>video/delete/<?php echo $myvid->id; ?>" onclick = "if (! confirm('Are your sure you want to delete this video? <?php echo $myvid->video_title; ?>')) return false;" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

I saw in a forum people talked about `DB::expr` to achive this but can find any example about it.

Could please someone give me a hint?

Comment: I suppose you can check for `$deletevideo` right after it's initialized; if it's null (or just an empty array; whatever this `find` method returns), redirect it, if not, proceed with checking the user identity.

Comment: now i feel stupid, i dont know why i didnt thought about that

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should get you going:

```
$video = Model_Video::find($id);

if ( ! $video instanceof Model_Video)
{
    Session::set_flash('fail', 'The video ID is not valid!');
    Response::redirect('go/somewhere/else');
}
```

You should always check if the result is in fact a valid Model_Video before using it.